# What type of a value (or data) is stored in a variable having a datatype of the same name as its parent class name?

Tags: java, class, oop, linked-list, concept

In the following code snippet:

```
class Node{
    Node next;
    String data;

    Node(String data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

What kind of data is being stored in the variable `next` which is assigned a datatype `Node` which is the same name as its class name? Also, please tell me the significance of such types of variables which are assigned a datatype with the same name as its parent class name.

Comment: `next` is another `Node`. It's a recursive definition. A `Node` contains a reference to another `Node`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Linked List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571503/understanding-linked-list-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

next is just a reference variable which is a type of Node.
Currently this reference  variable is null as it is not assigned with any value.